# Particles do not appear in object mode but do appear in vertex paint and weight paint modes. Also not possible to render

Tags: rendering, particles, export, weight-painting, object-mode

I create a model of a coffee tree [image] using Mtree Mesh addon and I´m trying to add some particles attached to some areas of the branches (as fruits). I use weight paint to do that and works well in vertex paint and weight paint modes but the particles move to the bottom of the tree in edit and object modes. Viewport and Render icons are active. Also, Particles aren´t appearing properly when render and when I export the model to .obj or .fbx the particles are missing.

The model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VbrS_WFrqXY0N_TZJmLZ1sgIbNdCXbYI/view?usp=sharing

Thank you all

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason the particles are not showing up is because the Use Modifier Stack is turned off in the particle system.

If you turn that on now the particles will show up.  You can also get the same effect by dragging the particle system modifier above the decimate modifier.

[image]
[image]